# Problem with javax.xml in OpenJDK 11 and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project in OpenJDK 11 and Eclipse 2019-12, which previously with Win7 was fully functional. I upgraded to Win10 and once I rebuilt it, here's what happened:

I get the following error:

"The package javax.xml.transform.stream is accessible from more than one module: unnamed, java.xml" "The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: unnamed, java.xml"

I try to solve it by going to Properties/Java Build Path and removing the java.xml module. The previous problems are fixed, but now the following ones appear:

"The import org.w3c.dom.CDATASection cannot be resolved" "The import javax.xml.transform cannot be resolved"

If I add the module again, the previous thing is fixed but the first errors that I have put appear. I don't know what to do anymore.

I have no idea why I have these problems now that I didn't have before, I don't know if it's Eclipse's problem or what, and the truth is quite frustrating.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance. Best regards.